# Use of QuickParts in Word Templates in combination with Site Content Types

Tags: content-type, word, document-template, document-info-panel

**Situation:**

- A Site ContentType (CT): Report (Parent =  Document)
- A Word Template is attached to the report CT
- 1 root site with several subsites (A, B, C)
- Every subsite contains a library with the 'Report' CT
- I created a new document 'template' on library of subsite B. Added the quickpart (metadata of type text and choice). I followed the steps explained in the following post: http://epiciw.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/using-quick-parts-to-automatically-update-fields-in-a-microsoft-office-document-from-the-metadata-in-a-sharepoint-document-library/
- I attached the new document template to the report Site CT

**Problem:**

- When I create a new document in subsite B - my quickparts are working.
- When I create a new document in the library in subsite C - my
  quickparts don't work. My Document Information Panel is not in sync with the quickparts.  And thus it's not possible to set my metadata with those quickparts.

  It seems like he's pointing to the wrong URL. Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like quickparts can only be scoped at document library level. So you need to set a template for every LIST content type. Not ideal, but I think we have to live with it for now...

Answer (score 7):

This problem is caused by differences in the SourceID property of the metadata fields. If you compare the value of SourceID on a field of a content type in one library with the same field of a content type in another library you will see that they differ, and they are used inside the Word document when referencing the metadata field.

The solution is to set SourceID to a fixed guid. Since it is a readonly property it has to be changed by altering the xml schema of that field, for example like this:

```
private static void SetSourceID(SPWeb web, string fieldName, string guid)
{
    SPField webField = (SPField) web.Fields[fieldName];

    XElement schema = XElement.Parse(webField.SchemaXml);
    XAttribute sourceID = schema.Attribute("SourceID");
    if (sourceID == null)
    {
        sourceID = new XAttribute("SourceID", guid);
        schema.Add(sourceID);
    }

    webField.SchemaXml = schema.ToString();
    webField.Update(true);
}
```

Comment: Oskar, can you explain a little more please? Should the SourceID attribute be set at the site or list content type level? Should it just be set to any random GUID?

Comment: Frankly I don't remember exactly since I haven't worked with SharePoint development for the last three years. But I suppose the important thing is to have the same source id (a random guid) on both fields of both content types. If you have a dev environment you should be able to verify that without too much effort.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for responding after your answer from 3 years ago! It sounds like it will be a hassle to maintain the source IDs, for example if a new column is added to the content type, which is then filtered down to the list content types, we will need to set the source ID of the new column at the site level and then at the list levels of alllll the lists that use this content type. Why couldn't Microsoft just have implemented this themselves!!